# Remove elements from a list in R based on a condition

Tags: r, list

I have a list `l` in R as shown below. I want to remove elements where the only alphanumeric character is 0. How can I do that?

```
# Create list
l <- list(c('108', '50', '0]'), c('109','58','0','0]'), c('18','0'))
l
[[1]]
[1] "108" "50"  "0]" 
[[2]]
[1] "109" "58"  "0"   "0]" 
[[3]]
[1] "18" "0" 

# What I want:
l
[[1]]
[1] "108" "50" 
[[2]]
[1] "109" "58" 
[[3]]
[1] "18"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to match either `0` or the `]` and negate (`!`) to remove the values from the `list` elements

```
lapply(l, function(x) x[!grepl("^0$|\\]", x)])
#[[1]]
#[1] "108" "50" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "109" "58" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "18"
```

---

Or convert to `numeric` remove the `NA` elements along with 0

```
lapply(l, function(x) x[!is.na(as.numeric(x)) & x != 0])
```

---

Or use `setdiff`

```
lapply(l, setdiff, c("0", "0]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a general purpose way.

```
l2 <- lapply(l, function(s) {
  s <- gsub('[^[:digit:]]', '', s)
  s[nchar(sub('([^0]*)0([^0]*)', '\\1\\2', s)) != 0]
  })

l2
#[[1]]
#[1] "108" "50" 
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "109" "58" 
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "18"
```

Answer (score 1):

An even more general solution, that removes potential elements like `"&% 00]"` (where the only alphanumeric characters are `0`)

```
lapply(l, function(x) x[grep('^[0[:punct:][:blank:]]*$', x, invert = TRUE)])
```